# Помогите раскрыть JSON

Tags: javascript, json

Добрый вечер!
 Помогите пожалуйста раскрыть JSON ответ

```js
response: {
count: 690,
items: [{
id: 172823,
first_name: 'Andrey',
```

Как вытащить отсюда id и first_name?

Вот, например, из этого кода

```js
response: [{
id: 205387401,
first_name: 'Tom',
last_name: 'Cruise
```

```
var fname =resp.response[0].first_name ;
```

получается таким образом. А как вытянуть массив из объекта??

Comment: Не очень понятно, что вы хотите получить в результате. Добавьте, пожалуйста, в вопрос информацию о том какой результат нужен.

Comment: нужно вывести содержимое id: и first_name:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Доступ к элементам объекта в примере ниже. Не забываем, что в примере объект, немного отличается от JSON. Если у вас JSON, предварительно его обработать JSON.parse() функцией, `response = JSON.parse(someJson);`

Вытащенный массив - две последние строки.

Про доступ:

```js
$(function(){
 var response = {
  col: 5,
  items: [
   {
    id: 5,
    animal: 'Cow'
   },
   {
    id: 36,
    animal: 'Petuh'
   }
  ]
 }

 $('#res').html('response.col: ' + response.col + '<br>');
 $('#res').html($('#res').html() + 'response.items[0].animal: ' + response.items[0].animal + '<br>');
 $('#res').html($('#res').html() + 'response.items[1].id: ' + response.items[1].id + '<br><br>');


 var arr = response.items[1];
 $('#res').html($('#res').html() + 'arr.animal: ' + arr.animal + '<br>');
 $('#res').html($('#res').html() + 'arr.id: ' + arr.id + '<br>');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="res"></div>
```